# Exporting Test Cases from Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: tfs, testcase, azure-devops

I don't see anywhere where I can simply export all the test cases from my instance of Visual Studio Team Services. This is *not* to be confused with regular Team Foundation Server. This is the hosted version by Microsoft and is a SaaS application.

Any way to export the test cases into Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use this tool [`Export Test Cases From TFS`](http://exporttfs2excel.codeplex.com/). (Dedicated for Excel)  This tool is good because you can have result and steps.

You can also use [`Test Scribe`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9975b601-beca-4553-b4cc-f6d34ab6394e) (Dedicated for Work)

Or you can use a `WIQL query` and export to Excel.